# Pass parameter to pentaho CDE report

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I created a CDE parameter report in this report I want pass parameter through url my CDE report link as below

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/pentaho-cdf-dd/Render?solution=demo&path=&file=pass_parameter.wcdf&userid=joe&password=password
```

and my cda query url as below

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/cda/doQuery?path=demo/pass_parameter.cda&dataAccessId=jdbc&paramdeviceType=deviceType
```

In above cda query url if I pass deviceType as below

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/cda/doQuery?path=demo/pass_parameter.cda&dataAccessId=jdbc&paramdeviceType=Linux
```

It shows me a json formatted output in browser. So I used CDE report in iframe on my jsp page and that iframe I pass first url. I want to pass deviceType parameter in my first url like

```
 http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/pentaho-cdf-dd/Render?solution=demo&path=&file=pass_parameter.wcdf&userid=joe&password=password&deviceType=Linux
```

but it not display any output, how I pass parameter through url?

Comment: can you please provide me  link how to start from begining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long researching I found solution of my questions.
First in my jndi query component query required attribute value and that attribute value I want to pass through url for this I select one component parameter and write javascript code as below

```
function() 
{ 
  cname = Dashboards.getQueryParameter('name');
 }
```

you can also this script to your component under pre execution and add parameter name as cname value also cname and my query will `select * from table name where cname=${cname}`. and in my iframe url I pass argument as below

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/pentaho-cdf-dd/Render?solution=demo&path=&file=pass_parameter.wcdf&userid=joe&password=password&name=Linux
```

and it shows me a results which I want.