# how to pass login credential in pentaho bi url

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

[Pass parameter to pentaho CDE report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377363/pass-parameter-to-pentaho-cde-report)

Request parameter using GET method is working fine but I dont want to show credentials in URL , post method is not working

```
requestParameterProcessingFilter : http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-10708

<html>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/ublic:Company:Reporting:Test:Test2.prpt/report?&output-target=pageable%2Fpdf" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="admin"/>
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't expect that to work.

You should look into granting anonymous access to Pentaho. You can find that in the infocenter.

Comment: Hi , in infocenter mention only for get method, but for post method is not working. Like payment gateway

Comment: Look at infocenter for information on enabling anonymous access. What you're trying to do won't work.

Comment: check my answer on how to grant anonymous access. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404241/pentaho-bi-server-report-without-log-in/28414637#28414637

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help but you can try with Authorization header. Where value of header is `"Basic " + Base64.encode64(username + ":" + password)`